# Eliminating duplicates such that the only records that remain were unique

Tags: excel, vba

I would like help with a couple of examples which would easily solve the following condition:

I have a record set with duplicates similar to this in a single column:

```
a
b
b
c
c
c
d
f
f
```

Is there an Excel function or VBA code that would display only records which are not duplicated? (true count of 1)

In the above example, such a function or code would only return records "a" and "d".

I already have a Pivot Table solution, but I am looking for something that would help an individual that does NOT want to use a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if `a` is in A2, A1 does not also contain `a` and you list is sorted, in B2 and copied down to suit:

```
 =(A2<>A1)*(A2<>A3)
```

then filter to select `1` in ColumnB.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data begins in A1, and the column full of data has a range name of **Data**, go into a blank column and enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Data,A1)=1,A1,"")
```

Then copy down the column to the end of the data. This produces the "minimal answer" where a blank is displayed next to records that are not unique, while the data is shown if it is. At that point if I wanted to narrow things down I'd slap a filter on it and filter out the blanks.

Answer (score -1):

Go to data > advanced filter. Select the option and the input range. Then check show unique records only.